# Application crashes after "Update DATABASE by heroku-postgresql"

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Since yesterday, when heroku-postgresql made an automatic update to the add-on, the application doesn't open anymore. Instead, it crashed with a
`"error error: password authentication failed for user "neyzbgqnexgsom""` message that I can see in the Heroku logs tail.

[image: Screenshot]

My app was working fine for about 3 months, and it started crashing right after this. How can I make it work back again?

Comment: I have the same problem. Also can't connect to database with provided credentials, it seems like they have changed them. Any good news?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that after that update, the `DATABASE_URL` config variable has changed. You must populate the Config Vars once again with the new values from the `DATABASE_URL`.